# How to change the color of UINavigation Left men Item in JSQMessenger with Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I add Left Navigation Menu Bar in JSQMessenger view controller.

```
 myBackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomerMessaging.popToRoot(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
 myBackButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "navigationbar_image"), for: .normal)
 myBackButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
 myBackButton.sizeToFit()

let myCustomBackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBackButton)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = myCustomBackButtonItem
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

I add back button image. The image is Blue back button. But, I set "White" color of tint color in  Attributes Inspector. It changes into "white" in other view controller.

But for JSQMessengerViewController, I add above code. But it does not change into "White" color. Please anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with the image asset itself you can change it to a template type in your `image.assets` folder. or programmatically just change your image `Rendering Mode`

```
self.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```